# How to shape data into grouped items in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following structure coming from the database:

```
[
    {
        "databaseId": 1,
        "databaseName": "Database1",
        "schemaName": "someschema",
        "schemaOwner": "dbo"
    },
    {
        "databaseId": 1,
        "databaseName": "Database1",
        "schemaName": "dbo",
        "schemaOwner": "dbo"
    },
    {
        "databaseId": 2,
        "databaseName": "Database2",
        "schemaName": "dbo",
        "schemaOwner": "dbo"
    }
]
```

I'd like to shape them into the following:

```
[
    {
        "databaseName": "Database1",
        "databaseId" 1,
        "schemas": [
            {
                "schemaName": "someschema",
                "schemaOwner": "dbo"
            },
            {
                "schemaName": "dbo",
                "schemaOwner": "dbo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "databaseName": "Database2",
        "databaseId" 2,
        "schemas": [
            {
                "schemaName": "dbo",
                "schemaOwner": "dbo"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
      var schemasGrouped = schemas.GroupBy(s => s.DatabaseName)
      .Select(g => new {DatabaseName = g.Key, Schemas = g.ToList()})
      .ToList();
```

But this does not give me what I want as it does not list the database Id in the parent document, it also lists all properties in the child, even though I only want SchemaName and SchemaOwner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add element selector `Func` to [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) overload, as well as use two fields in group key

```cs
var schemasGrouped = schemas
    .GroupBy(s => { s.DatabaseName, s.DatabaseId }, s => new { s.schemaName, s.schemaOwner})
    .Select(g => new { DatabaseName = g.Key.DatabaseName, DatabaseId = g.Key.DatabaseId, Schemas = g.ToList()})
    .ToList();
```